# jquery attribute states it is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a bit of code I'm trying to get working, however I seem to be going round in circles at the moment.

The aim is to stop the immediate click event, do something then continue.

I've swapped from window.open to window.location to window.replace but not got one to act as I need it to as yet.

With the current code below, the variable href is undefined.

Any help appreciated - I know very little javascript.

```
$("ul.tabs li").click(function (e) {

    var href = $(this).attr("href");

    e.preventDefault();

    setTimeout("location.replace(" + href + ");",2000);
});
```

Comment: `<li>` elements usually don't have `href` attributes. `<a>` elements do. Also, `"location.replace(" + href + ")"` will result in invalid JS. Pass a function to `setTimeout`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout

Comment: Look at what `this` actually is when your code runs. It's probably not what you think it is. What does your html look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `li` doesn't have a `href` attribute.

```
$("ul.tabs li a").click(function (e) {

        var href = $(this).attr("href");

        e.preventDefault();

        setTimeout(function() {document.location.replace(href);},2000);
    });
```

Or you can do `$(this).find('a').attr('href');` if you want to apply the `click` event to `li` elements

Comment: `setTimeout("location.replace(" + href + ");",2000);` won't work as it is.

Comment: Lol, too close to the code - appreciate it.

Comment: What's up with `/pattern/`? That's not how `location.replace` works: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/replace

Comment: I updated the answer, I thought, location is a string that will be replaced! :p

Comment: Thanks guys - its now working. That's what happens when you put a c# guy in charge of a UI

Comment: You're welcome! :) So would you set it to resolve if it works! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("ul.tabs li").click(function (e) {
// or use $("ul.tabs li a") and don't write .find('a') below

var href = $(this).find('a').attr("href");


e.preventDefault();

setTimeout(function()
   {
      location.replace(href);
    },2000);
});
```

JsFiddle doesn't work right now so here's [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vONwBY)

Comment: It is correction if you do: `$(this).find('a').attr('href');`, in your code, `href` is `undefined`

Comment: How exactly does this solve the problem that `href` is `undefined`?

Comment: It might be undefined only if the A element does not have a href attribute  set. I actually posted a link to codePen with a console.log(href) and it works

Comment: Sure, after the suggested edit. I was referring to the original version.